# Unable to connect to a MongoDB using Django in Pycharm

Tags: python, django, mongodb

I am attempting to create a basic application to get a better understanding of Django. I would really like to use a MongoDB database, and have MongoDB set up locally on my machine. I am able to connect via MongoDB Compass and have created some basic collections/dbs.

In my Django application, I have djongo and pymongo installed. My `pip list`.

```
Package     Version
----------- -------
asgiref     3.2.3  
dataclasses 0.6    
Django      3.0    
djongo      1.2.38 
pip         19.3.1 
pymongo     3.10.0 
pytz        2019.3 
setuptools  42.0.2 
sqlparse    0.2.4  
wheel       0.33.6
```

In the `settings.py` I have my DATABASES set up as follows:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'djongo',
        'NAME': 'djongo',
        'HOST': 'localhost:27017/djongo',
    }
}
```

When I attempt to run a migration, I get the following error.

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: 'djongo' isn't an available database backend.
Try using 'django.db.backends.XXX', where XXX is one of:
    'mysql', 'oracle', 'postgresql', 'sqlite3'
```

I have seen similar posts online, but the solutions (ensuring djongo is installed) have not been working.

How can I use a MongoDB database with a Django application?

Comment: Are you using a virtual environment by any chance? If you do ```pip freeze``` can you see the package ```djongo``` listed?

Comment: @Paolo I am using a virtual env, under `pip freeze` I can see `djongo==1.2.38`.

Comment: Interesting, have you tried reinstalling all packages? Or maybe create a new virtual environment and then proceed reinstalling the packages?

Comment: @Paolo I had issues with my first project, so I created a new env and attempted doing it again but getting the same error.

Comment: What version of Python are you using? Cause I noticed you're using Django 3.0.

Comment: @Paolo Currently using python 3.7.5

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204081/discussion-between-paolo-and-childishforlife).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Django 3.0 was just released not too long ago which is why `djongo` wouldn't work ***yet***. Was able to test this, and had no success. After downgrading to Django 2.2 that worked for OP.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use mongoengine or pymongo to connect to mongodb database instead of djongo.

For mongoengine see this answer:-
[Setting up Django and mongodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48243517/setting-up-django-and-mongodb/59396155#59396155)